Unable to run Angular solution due to version mismatch
I am getting the below error when trying to run the angular solution through VS Code.

This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^18.0.0,
but Angular version 13.3.12 was found instead.

Below are the version details:

Angular CLI: 13.3.10

Node: 19.9.0 (Unsupported)

Package Manager: npm 10.7.0

Angular: 13.3.12


How do I solve this error?

install a supported Node version and a supported angular cli version

Use the locally installed version of Angular CLI rather than the global version.

Install the local version of Angular CLI: npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@13.3.10
Run Angular CLI commands using npx: npx ng serve / "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && node --max_old_space_size=10000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve"


You can install node version 16 using nvm to run the angular application, it's an immediate solution.
And going forward please update your angular to the latest version 18 to work on the latest.

I tried it. Its asking me to update node version to 18.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of v18.19.

Here's the compatibility page, if you have not used it before in the Angular website:

https://v17.angular.io/guide/versions

Also, if you want to automatically use the version installed in your apps, use npm tasks instead of ng command.
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve"
}

npm start will use your local version declared in the package.json, while ng serve will use the globally installed one.
